# Combine string Scrapy python

Tags: python, json, join, scrapy, concatenation

I have a question about how to combine a set of values when using scrapy so that my json output is cleaner.  Here is what I have:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join

class LLPubs (scrapy.Spider):
    name = "linlinks"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/1',
        'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/2',
        'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/2a',
        'http://www.linnaeuslink.org/records/record/10',
]

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css('div.item'):
            yield {
                'text': item.css('div.field.soulsbyNo .value span::text').extract(),
                'uniformtitle': item.css('div.field.uniformTitle .value span::text').extract(),
                'title': item.css('div.field.title .value span::text').extract(),
                'opac': item.css('div.field.localControlNo .value span::text').extract(),
                'digitalcopyurl': .join(response.css('div#digitalLinks li a').xpath('@href').extract()),
                'name': response.css('div#digitalLinks li a span::text').extract(),
                }
```

The "digitalcopyurl" is where I am having the problem.  I guess I can't use "join" in this way but I'm not sure what to modify.  Here's an example of what the JSON looks like now:

```
{"text": ["Soulsby no. 46(1)"], 
"uniformtitle": ["Systema naturae"], 
"title": ["Caroli Linnæi ... Systema naturæ\nin quo naturæ regna tria, secundum classes, ordines, genera, species, systematice proponuntur."], 
"opac": ["002178079"], 
"digitalcopyurl": ["http://books.google.co.uk/books?vid=BL:A0019621817", "http://books.google.co.uk/books?vid=BL:A0019621817", "", ""], 
"name": ["View digital version at BL", "View digital version at BL", "View digital version at NHM-LONDON", "View digital version at UUL"]},
```

I would like the "digitalcopyurl" to look more like:

```
"digitalcopyurl": ["http://books.google.co.uk/books?vid=BL:A0019621817, http://books.google.co.uk/books?vid=BL:A0019621817"],
```

(And I would like to use the same solution to do the same to the "name" field.)

Thanks for your help!

Edit: The example output is NOT using the ".join"--it's without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write

```
'digitalcopyurl': ", ".join(response.css('div#digitalLinks li a').xpath('@href').extract())
```

OR

```
'digitalcopyurl': ", ".join(a.strip() for a in response.css('div#digitalLinks li a').xpath('@href').extract())
```

Both will do the same thing

Comment: Ah!  Thanks so much.